# Graphical file manager with VIM keybindings

Tags: linux, open-source, file-management, vim

To sort fotos quickly I like to drag 'n' drop them in a graphical file manager (currently Thunar) with previews.

I'd like to have a **file manager with previews/thumbnails and a vim-like interface**. Vim-like interface means to me supporting regexing, a nice ex and search mode as well as the obvious vim keybindings.

Please do only propose open source software (or even better FLOSS) which can be used on linux.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the exact "Graphical" file manager that you might have wanted, but your should definitely give [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) a try. It's a VIM-inspired file manager for the console.

Although it's console based it has all of the features(even better in my opinion), as you wanted. It is built with minimalism and is vim based in all sorts.

- [You can preview images](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Image-Previews)
- You can move around using vim keybindings. For example : You can mark a directory you visit often to **register a**, with <kbd>ma</kbd>. Then move to that directory by, you guessed it, <kbd>`a</kbd>.
- You can bulkrename files
- You can of course sort files in different styles. Just use the <kbd>o</kbd> key and a menu will popup providing the possible sort options.
- visually select items and perform operations on them.
- Set your own color scheme and more

Most importantly it's an open source project fully written in python. It's highly extensible. You can create your own custom commands(say a command to upload selected images to imgur), you can [integrate ranger with other applications](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Integration-with-other-programs) like vim,emacs etc.

You just defintely give it a try. It's very much productive in the long run.